# how to display content horizontally in a hidden div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have  hidden `div` and there is some content  when `div` is been displayed the content should displayed in horizontally not vertically ?

the `div` will be displayed when i click on button.

```
<div class = "firstHidden">
    <h4> Account No </h4>
    <h5> 123456789 </h5>
    <h4> Service Address </h4>
    <h5> 49, Rampasture Raod, Hampton</h5>
    <h4> Amount Due </h4>
    <h5> payment Date : 09/12/2015 </h5>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post some of your code and describe your problem more clearly. What do you see now? What do you want to see?

Comment: Please provide code?

Comment: Your question is not clear, please provide your tried code.

Comment: By default all the contents are horizontal i guess. Please make your question clearer.

Comment: Please provide css + html example (with parent divs), your problem is probably div's width and/or css

Answer (score 1):

try this css

```
.firstHidden h4, .firstHidden h5{
     float:left;
     padding-right:10px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your CSS: Adjust the div's width to your requirement.

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css class

```
.toCenterHorizontally{
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 10px;
}
```